# Select rows on list of paired column values in NHibernate LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a set of unique `int` pairs that might look like the following: (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), etc. They can be in whatever data structure is most convenient (e.g. `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`, `List<Tuple<int, int>>`, `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`, etc.).

I need to select all the rows in a particular database table where `col1` and `col2` match respectively the first and second values in any of the pairs. So, using the example pairs above, a row with 2 in `col1` and 3 in `col2` would be selected, while a row with 2 in `col1` and 4 in `col2` would not.

If this were for a normal collection with standard LINQ, it could be done pretty simply:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
...
var result = collection.Where(row => pairs.Contains(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(row.col1, row.col2));
```

or

```
var pairs = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
...
var result = collection.Where(row => pairs.ContainsKey(row.col1) && pairs[row.col1].Contains(row.col2));
```

However, this kind of thing is not supported by NHibernate. What is the best way to write this query in a way that NHibernate understands?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

// fill list of typles somehow...

var result = from c in collection
             from p in pairs
             where c.Item1 == p.Item1 && c.Item2 == p.Item2
             select c;
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it doesn't look like it's supported in NHibernate either.